# Left Align Equations with textcolor{red}{boxed}

Tags: equations, alignment

I have this code

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\newcommand{\Tonde}[1]{\left(#1\right)}
\newcommand{\tonde}[1]{\bigl(#1\bigr)}
\begin{document}
\begin{flalign}
\textcolor{red}{\boxed{V\tonde{r,\theta}=\frac{3}{\varepsilon+2}Er\cos\theta}}\\
\textcolor{red}{\boxed{W\tonde{r,\theta}=Er\cos\theta\Tonde{1+\frac{1-\varepsilon}{2+\varepsilon}\frac{R^3}{r^3}}}}
\end{flalign}

\begin{align}
V\tonde{r,\theta}&=\frac{3}{\varepsilon+2}Er\cos\theta\\
W\tonde{r,\theta}&=Er\cos\theta\Tonde{1+\frac{1-\varepsilon}{2+\varepsilon}\frac{R^3}{r^3}}
\end{align}

\end{document}
```

and I'd like to left-align the red equations at sign of = like as the black equations below.

Is it possible? Thank you so much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If a tricky version is also OK...

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\newcommand{\Tonde}[1]{\left(#1\right)}
\newcommand{\tonde}[1]{\bigl(#1\bigr)}
\begin{document}

\newlength\Wl
\settowidth\Wl{$W$}
%\begin{flalign}
\begin{align}
&\textcolor{red}{\boxed{\makebox[\Wl][r]{$V$}\tonde{r,\theta}=\frac{3}{\varepsilon+2}Er\cos\theta}}\\
&\textcolor{red}{\boxed{W\tonde{r,\theta}=Er\cos\theta\Tonde{1+\frac{1-\varepsilon}{2+\varepsilon}\frac{R^3}{r^3}}}}
%\end{flalign}
\end{align}

\begin{align}
V\tonde{r,\theta}&=\frac{3}{\varepsilon+2}Er\cos\theta\\
W\tonde{r,\theta}&=Er\cos\theta\Tonde{1+\frac{1-\varepsilon}{2+\varepsilon}\frac{R^3}{r^3}}
\end{align}

\end{document}
```

[image]